# What happened when I change the variable 'x' to 'fab'?Something about decorator and pass the function variable

Tags: python

I define a Factorial function named `fab`. I use generator to avoid stack overflow.But something I can't understand came up when I try to write a decorator version, which is more intuitive :

```
import types

def TCO(f):    
    def inner(*nkw,**kw):
        gen=f(*nkw,**kw)
        while isinstance(gen,types.GeneratorType):
            gen=gen.next()
        return gen
    return inner



def fab(n,s=1):
    if n<2:
        yield s
    else:
        yield fab(n-1,s*n)


x=TCO(fab)
print x(2500) #this works fine, overcoming the limitation of tail-recursion.

fab=TCO(fab) #now just change the variable name.
print fab(5) #this woks fine.
print fab(2500) #this will raise an error :maximum recursion limit exceeded
```

**Why? I know it has something to do with the same name `fab`**, but why `fab(5)` works fine? I think when I define `fab=TCO(fab)`, I actually change the object refered by `f` in `inner` to object `TCO(fab)`. So when fab(5) runs, the `gen` will never be a generator! Because the `inner` never returns generator!

I am mad...Why ?

Comment: A generator that yields exactly once should be a function.

Comment: @Alfe Situations are different , if I use `return` , it is the same as ordinary tail-recursion form in python and suffers recursion limit.

Comment: You could return a lambda to avoid immediate evaluation.  I feel to use a generator here is not clearing things up but rather hides the true intention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
fab=TCO(fab)
```

statment now makes the variable `fab` points to the function `inner`. After that, when

```
yield fab(n-1,s*n)
```

is encountered, it is not actually calling the original `fab` function but the `inner` function which in turn calls the original `fab` function. Basically, you are coming out of the generator and entering another function every time. Thats why you are getting `maximum recursion limit exceeded` error.

Comment: Is that means, `f` in `inner` still refers to original `fab`, but when code is executed, the chars `fab` in original `fab` refers to `inner`?

Comment: I forget to @= =. Please look upward

Comment: @Pythoner Yes you are correct. `f` in `inner` still refers to original `fab` but as we reassign it, `fab` points to `inner`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this would be a good example to explain what happens:

```
def f(x):
    print 'original'
    if x > 0:
        return f(x-1)
    return 0
g = f
def f(x):
    print 'new'
    return x
print g(5)
```

result:

```
original
new
4
```

this proves:

```
1.when g(5) runs, origninal `f` is called, not new `f`.
2.as 5>0, 'return f(x-1)' is executed
3.new `f` is called when `f(x-1)` runs. so the result is 4.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your original version yields a generator which yields a generator which yields a generator, etc.  To evaluate that linked list you then use the `while` loop in you `TCO` decorator.  It all is based on the fact that you are linking generators to avoid a large stack.

This concept is broken when you assign something new to the variable `fab`.  Then `yield`ing `fab(n-1, s*n)` in `fab` is accessing the new `fab` variable and thus not returning a generator anymore but a value.  To compute that value, the stack is used, hence you can get the stack overflow problem.